# Identification of a tagged person on photo

Tags: pattern-recognition

I'm not sure if this problem was discussed before - if so could anyone please provide the link.
The problem is the following: let's say I have a photo with some person who is tagged there, in the same way as in Facebook - there is the square which contain some part of person's body, usually the head.
Question is: what is the easiest way to get the profile of this person?
To crop the person out of the image to be able to process it separately.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you call profile of person?

Comment: Contour of the person, the curve around him or her. My aim is to cut the person out of the photo, that's what I mean.